# Morse–Palais Lemma and local approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold and let $E:\Lambda M\to\mathbb{R}$ be the energy functional $E[\gamma]=\int_{S^1}||\dot\gamma(t)||^2dt$ where $\Lambda M$ is the free loop space of $M$, i.e. the manifold of loops $H^1(S^1,M)$ of Sobolev class $H^1$. Then the manifold $\Lambda M$ is a Hilbert manifold. Assume that the Riemannian metric on $M$ is chosen such that the energy functional $E$ on $\Lambda M$ is Morse-Bott. Then we know it is a $C^2$-function. Assume that it is also $C^3$ (I am not too sure if there is a way to choose this). Assume $\beta$ is a non-degenerate critical point of $E$. Then there are convex neighborhoods $V$ and $U$ of $\beta$, a diffeomorphism (of class $C^1$) $\varphi:U\to V$ with $\varphi(\beta)=\beta$ and a bounded orthogonal projection $P:\Lambda M \to \Lambda M$ such that $E[\gamma]=E[\beta]-||P(\varphi(\gamma))||_{\Lambda M}^2+||\varphi(\gamma)-P(\varphi(\gamma))||_{\Lambda M}^2$ for the orthogonal decomposition $\Lambda M=G\oplus G^{\perp}$ and the $H^1$-inner product $\langle\xi,\eta \rangle=\int_{S^1}\langle\xi,\eta\rangle+\int_{S^1}\langle D_t\xi,D_t\eta\rangle=\langle\xi,\eta\rangle_0+\langle D_t\xi,D_t\eta\rangle_0$. The dimension of the space $Im(P)$ coincides with the Morse index of the critical point $\beta$.

> How do we find the projection map $P$ and the diffeomorphism $\varphi$ to express $E[\gamma]=E[\beta]-||P(\varphi(\gamma))||_{\Lambda M}^2+||\varphi(\gamma)-P(\varphi(\gamma))||_{\Lambda M}^2$ in local coordinates on $\Lambda M$?

I am looking for something similar to the ordinary Morse lemma, which asserts for $f : M\to\mathbb{R}$, there exists a chart $(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $\beta$ such that $x_i(\beta)=\beta$, $\forall i$ and $f(x)=f(b)-x_1^2-...-x_{\alpha}^2+x_{\alpha+1}^2+...+x_n^2$ on $U$ where $\alpha$ is equal to the index of $f$ at $\beta$.

See [theorem 3](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Morse_lemma) for reference.

---

Cross-posted on MO.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curiosity: did you find this in a book/paper? I would like to read it too.
Is your question about the proof of the Morse-Palais Lemma? It seems to me that you want to understand the construction of the diffeomorphism $\Psi$.

Comment: Hi @WarlockofFiretopMountain, this can be found in [this text](http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/morsecourse/biglectures.pdf) on page 153 or, for quick reference, this [enclyclopedia](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Morse_lemma). Yes, I would like to explicitly write down this diffeomorphism.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain [This is also a very good source](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183535423).